# UIViewController class with <generic> gives error "Unknown class in Interface Builder file"

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'd like to have a view controller that can display an object that conforms to a protocol with an associated type ([PAT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWoNjiSPqI8)).

I can't really avoid using a PAT, but I'd love to have a view controller that's able to display any object that conforms to this protocol.

Everything compiles fine, and interface builder auto-completes the classname just fine, but at runtime I get this error:

> Unknown class _TtC14api_collection17ModelPrinter in Interface Builder file.

I've looked at other Q&A for this error message, and in all the cases I've found it was about the storyboard coming out of sync with what's really going on, and that isn't the case here.

Here is my class definition:

```
class ModelPrinter<T where T: APIModel>: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
  var model: T?

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    textView.text = model?.name
  }
}
```

And here is where I instantiate the VC:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "ModelPrinter", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as? ModelPrinter<StarWarsPerson> {
      vc.model = latest[indexPath.row]
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
  }
```

Am I permitted to have a `UIViewController` class with a generic constraint? If so, how do I wire it up properly?